# Anyway I can make this function more concise

Tags: javascript, node.js

Given this code to validate if I have any missing fields in my config file

```
  if ( (typeof value === "string" && value.length > 0) || (Array.isArray(value) === true || value.length > 0) || Boolean(value) === true) {
    return value;
  } else {
    throw new Error(`Config value missing`);
  }
}
```

Comment: `Boolean(value) === true` includes all the other checks too. This piece either does not do what you want to, or you don't need al the others.

Comment: @JonasWilms it doesn't do an array length check. empty arrays are truthy in js

Comment: @bryan60 yup, so an empty array will also enter the if branch, so there's no sense to check for it's length at all.

Comment: @JonasWilms OP is indeed doing a weird check. I thought they were trying to check if the array is not empty but upon closer inspection they check if it's an array or it's got a length. Though i kind of suspect their intention is to throw an error on an empty array. Who knows though.

Comment: @JonasWilms the check I wanted to do was to make sure my config field has either of these ( a list that is not empty , a string, or a boolean)

Comment: that's not what your code does. Also none of the answers code do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not care about the type of `value`:

```js
if (value) {
  return value;
} else ...
```

If you care about the type of `value`

```js
const isValidType = typeof value === "string" || Array.isArray(value) || Boolean(value);

if ( value && isValidType) {
  return value;
} else...
```

Comment: `Boolean(value)` is a little of an overkill, you can just drop the casting and do `value` directly. Given the next line is `if ( value && isValidType)` it can be completely dropped, since the full expression you're evaluating is `value && (typeof value === "string" || Array.isArray(value) || Boolean(value))` which then leads to evaluating the logical sub-expression `value && Boolean(value)` and that's a tautology.